# How to fix "TypeError: 'KeyCode' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I'm learning about `pynput` and make this simple code.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
mouse = Controller()

try:
    while True:
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Interrupted")
```

And i don't know why this give me a:

```
TypeError: 'KeyCode' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post the *full* error message including stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

Ok.. now I have solution.
If I want both keyboard controller and mouse I need to import like this

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
```

and then use..

```
keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()
```